# Datatype of columns with null values only in python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find out the datatype of columns with null values only.

```
df.columns[df_test.isnull().sum()>0]
```

is giving me the list of columns which has null values , but i need the list of columns with datatypes.

Can you please help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I understand, you can use `loc` directly without using any loop.

```
df_test.loc[:,df_test.isnull().sum()>0].dtypes
```

An example below:

```
df = pd.util.testing.makeMissingDataframe().fillna({"A":0}).head(5)
print(df)
         A         B         C         D
UxNqePUQXH  0.449476  0.713696  1.255964 -0.458908
qBsuuVjimE  0.840831  0.439097  1.073890  1.252807
ptZvWjEdUV  0.377418  0.061335  0.960726  1.140141
LO54c7vqq1 -1.708196 -0.483487  0.831404       NaN
Pc7I7gTRZY       NaN -1.400275  0.045297 -0.322303

>>df.loc[:,df.isnull().sum()>0].dtypes

C    float64
D    float64
dtype: object
```

Note that you can also explore `any`:

```
df_test.loc[:,df_test.isnull().any()].dtypes.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

for x in df:
    if df[x].isna().any():
        print(df[x].dtype)
```

that is if the column contains a single null value. if you only want the datatype if ALL the values in the column are null, you can do the below

import pandas as pd

```
for x in df:
    if df[x].isna().all():
        print(df[x].dtype)
```